# Пояснение нюансов работы Yii2

Tags: yii2, auth, response

Использую для API HttpBasicAuth.

В yii\filters\auth\HttpBasicAuth есть функция

```
public function challenge($response)
{
    $response->getHeaders()->set('WWW-Authenticate', "Basic realm=\"{$this->realm}\"");
}
```

По дебагеру отследил, что переменная $response экземпляр класса yii\web\Response.

Т.е. идет вызов функции getHeaders(), но после чего идет новый вызов функции, set() которая относится к классу yii\web\HeaderCollection.

Как это возможно? Ведь по идее, чтобы функция set() должна находится в классе yii\web\Response.

Версии:
Yii: 2.0.14
PHP: 7.2.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В чем вопрос?

У объекта `$response` есть приватное свойство `$_headers` типа `HeaderCollection`. При вызове `getHeaders()` возвращается ссылка на это свойство (т.к. объекты всегда передаются в функцию и  возвращаются по ссылке, это нюансы работы PHP). Затем у этого объекта вызывается метод `set()`, который добавляет еще один заголовок в коллекцию. По сути заголовок добавляется в свойство `$_headers` объекта `$response`.

Если бы свойство `$_headers` было публичным, мы бы написали так:

```
$response->_headers->set('WWW-Authenticate', "Basic realm=\"{$this->realm}\"");
```

Comment: хм. Стало яснее теперь. Спасибо. 
Не обратил внимание на приватную переменную $_headers.

Ещё раз спасибо, что помогли разобраться.

Comment: Пожалуйста. Посоветую изучить руководство по PHP особенно касательно ООП